# moq objects Returns method, should return a null object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, mocking, moq, wcf-web-api

I'm developing a Web API, and one of the test I came up with is that, if client makes a GET operation with a Physical Test ID (Physical Test is the resource I'm looking for) and that physical test is not found, the web API should return a 404 status.

Now, I'm using moq framework for my tests and I have the following code:

```
[TestMethod]
public void then_if_physical_test_not_found_return_not_found_status()
{
    var unitOfWork = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    var repository = new Mock<IRepository<PhysicalTest>>();
    repository.Setup(r => r.FindById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns();
    unitOfWork.Setup(m => m.PhysicalTests).Returns(repository.Object);
    var pt = new PhysicalTestResource(unitOfWork.Object);
    HttpResponseMessage<PhysicalTest> response = pt.GetPhysicalTest(43);
    Assert.AreEqual(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, response.StatusCode)
}
```

I need the Returns() method to return a null object, which is going to be what the actual API method would return if the resource is not found.

I tried sending null as a parameter in the Returns() method but had no success.

Comment: To clarify, the error occurs because there are two overloads of `Returns`, one taking `T` (`T` = `IRepository<PhysicalTest>` in this case) and one taking `Func<T>`. When passing `null`, the compiler doesn't know which one to use, so you have to be specific. These overloads exist to give you the option to either return a static value `.Returns(new T())` or a new instance on every call `.Returns(() => new T())`.

Answer (score 292, accepted):

You don't indicate what the error was, but this should work:

```
unitOfWork.Setup(m => m.PhysicalTests).Returns((IRepository<PhysicalTest>)null);
```

I suspect you tried to call it with `Returns(null)`, which causes the compiler to complain since `Returns` is overloaded and it doesn't know which method should be called.  Casting to a specific type removes the ambiguity.

Comment: it worked, but I had to make this modification:
unitOfWork.Setup(m => m.PhysicalTests).Returns((PhysicalTest)null);

Comment: ah, ok... I assumed that since you were trying to return `repository.Object` that was the type returned by `PhysicalTests`.

Comment: I tried the same thing and I'm getting a System.NotSupportedException.  
{"Invalid setup on a non-virtual (overridable in VB) member: x => x.GetFoo(.value.Id)"}  Any ideas?

Comment: @DanCsharpster You can only use Moq on interfaces or abstract classes with virtual members. Whatever class you're using that is the type of `x` is either a concrete class or an abstract class that has `GetFoo()` as non-virtual/overridable.

Comment: I can recommend this way of resolving the overload ambiguity. I just want to mention that, since the two non-generic overloads of `Returns` which are important here, have different names for their parameter, you can also resolve the ambiguity by writing: `... .Returns(value: null)` (here `value` is just the name of the parameter in the overload we want, it is not a keyword).

Answer (score 12):

`rt` is a return type of method: `FindById`

`repository.Setup(r => r.FindById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(Task.FromResult((rt)null));`

Answer (score 11):

If you are receiving an error like this:

[image]

You just need to specify the input parameter of 'Returns' method.
Take a look in my example:

```
_ = _fileStorage.Setup(x => x.LoadDocument(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(value: null);
```

Answer (score 5):

`Organization` is a return type of method: `Get`

```
mockCache
    .Setup(cache => cache.Get(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(value: null as Organization);
```

Answer (score 2):

Along with casting the member to null as mentioned by the accepted answer, this approach should work as well.

```
unitOfWork.Setup(m => m.PhysicalTests).Returns(() => null);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```cs
ref1.Setup(s => s.Method(It.IsAny<Ref2>(), It.IsAny<string>()))
     .Returns((Task<Ref3>)null);

ref1 = Mock Interface
Ref2 = Type request parameter
Ref3 = Type of return method mock
```

Answer (score 0):

You're too close, you only need to pass the return type as generic type like so

```
repository.Setup(r => r.FindById(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns<IRepository<PhysicalTest>>(null);
```